# Bootstrap 4 equal height rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i made a gallery using bootstrap4 grids, each 6 images is a row, if one of the 6 images is taller than the others, The entire row's images become taller too, And i want to set a fixed size row so images just resize at its size, i use css

```
height: 100%; width 100%;
```

to make it fill the size of row because if i didn't all images will stat at its real height and width and become mass.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="normal-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="normal-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="tall-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="normal-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="normal-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="normal-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="normal-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="normal-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="normal-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="normal-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="normal-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="normal-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @ZimSystem if image is 200x300 and other is 150x250, with 100% i get the div filled to both images as 300x300, If i didn't use 100%, It stays as its normal size, And ruins every possible breakpoints view

Comment: ok, I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. how do you expect it to work? Do you expect the next row to perfectly align under the first row? Like a "masonry" effect?

Comment: @ZimSystem The problem isn't aligning, For example if first row had 1 picture 500x400 and the other 5 are 250x200 to compress the 500x400 to 250x200 even if that would ruin it.

Comment: That's because `col-lg-2` is only 16.6% wide. It's not because of the adjacent images. The larger image resizes the same regardless of the other images. Create an example like this: http://www.codeply.com/go/jUOwQZcoCr

Answer (score 0):

you can add custom css

`.img-fluid{ max-width:100%; max-height:100px; }`

Comment: all the image returns to its real size once i did that before.

Comment: Do you want to maintain the aspect ratio for the image ?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just add a CSS class to the images, last thing you want is a image getting uploaded and covering pretty much whole your site.

```
img.img-fluid {
 height: 250px;
}
```